# Constraint on HList: check for single occurrence of a type

Tags: scala, shapeless

I'm trying to add a constraint on an HList (from Shapeless):

- it should contain any arbitrary number of elements of type `TA` (from 0 to N);
- it should contain one and only one element of type `TB`.

My example has this type hierarchy:

```
trait T
case class TA extends T
case class TB extends T
```

To give examples:

- `tb :: HNil` is valid
- `ta :: tb ::HNil` is valid
- `ta :: tb :: ta :: HNil` is valid
- `ta :: HNil` is invalid
- `HNil` is invalid

I cannot figure out how to express this as a constraint.

Comment: Are other types allowed in the hlist?

Comment: Nope, only things that extend T (and there will probably be never any other types than TA and TB).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this with a custom type class that witnesses that there's exactly one `TB` and all the other elements are `TA`. If you imagine building up this list inductively, you'll see there are two cases you need to handle—either everything you've seen so far is a `TA` (which we can witness with a `ToList[T, TA]`) and the current element is a `TB`, or you've already seen a single `TB` and the current element is a `TA`:

```
import shapeless._, ops.hlist.{ ToList }

trait T
case class TA() extends T
case class TB() extends T

trait UniqueTB[L <: HList] extends DepFn1[L] {
  type Out = TB
  def apply(l: L): TB
}

object UniqueTB {
  def apply[L <: HList](implicit utb: UniqueTB[L]): UniqueTB[L] = utb
  def getTB[L <: HList](l: L)(implicit utb: UniqueTB[L]): TB = utb(l)

  implicit def firstTB[T <: HList](
    implicit tl: ToList[T, TA]
  ): UniqueTB[TB :: T] = new UniqueTB[TB :: T] {
    def apply(l: TB :: T): TB = l.head
  }

  implicit def afterTB[T <: HList](
    implicit utb: UniqueTB[T]
  ): UniqueTB[TA :: T] = new UniqueTB[TA :: T] {
    def apply(l: TA :: T): TB = utb(l.tail)
  }
}
```

And then:

```
scala> UniqueTB[TB :: HNil]
res0: UniqueTB[shapeless.::[TB,shapeless.HNil]] = UniqueTB$$anon$1@385c6929

scala> UniqueTB[TA :: TB :: HNil]
res1: UniqueTB[shapeless.::[TA,shapeless.::[TB,shapeless.HNil]]] = UniqueTB$$anon$2@682dd97e

scala> UniqueTB[TA :: TB :: TA :: HNil]
res2: UniqueTB[shapeless.::[TA,shapeless.::[TB,shapeless.::[TA,shapeless.HNil]]]] = UniqueTB$$anon$2@5ef48f82

scala> UniqueTB[TB :: HNil]
res3: UniqueTB[shapeless.::[TB,shapeless.HNil]] = UniqueTB$$anon$1@33be241

scala> UniqueTB[TA :: HNil]
<console>:25: error: could not find implicit value for parameter utb: UniqueTB[shapeless.::[TA,shapeless.HNil]]
       UniqueTB[TA :: HNil]
               ^

scala> UniqueTB[HNil]
<console>:25: error: could not find implicit value for parameter utb: UniqueTB[shapeless.HNil]
       UniqueTB[HNil]
               ^

scala> UniqueTB[TB :: TB :: HNil]
<console>:25: error: could not find implicit value for parameter utb: UniqueTB[shapeless.::[TB,shapeless.::[TB,shapeless.HNil]]]
       UniqueTB[TB :: TB :: HNil]
               ^
```

I've given the type class an operation that returns the `TB`, but if you don't need that you could leave it method-less.

Comment: I think you could use the IsHCons type class already provided by shapeless instead of creating a new one. The only remaining thing would be to define the `afterTB` in terms of the existing instances. What do you think?

Comment: Actually never mind, don't think you could do that. :|

Comment: @DenisRosca Yeah, I don't see how that would work, but I could be missing something.

Comment: Thanks a lot @TravisBrown! I just don't get how to use it with valued types (eg: case class TA(value: String)). How to pass instances instead of just types? I'm sure I'm missing some point here...

Comment: @AlbanDericbourg I've just added a `getTB` method to the answer. Just pass it an hlist value (the type will be inferred), and it'll compile if the hlist satisfies the constraint and won't otherwise.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you use a `case class` for `case class TA() extends T` rather than a `case object`?

Comment: I was following the OP, where I assume the members were elided.